# Can't get the right .ics format for outlook to recognize it as a request

Tags: javascript, outlook, icalendar

I'm working on confirmation emails and i need to send an .ics request by mail to ask the customer whether we can deliver at a certain time. As I am testing this, I can't respond from Outlook. When i try my gmail address I can reply perfectly. I'm thinking that maybe my formating is wrong?

I'm using [this ics library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ics)

Here is the relevant code:

```
const event = {
                start: [
                    startDate.getFullYear(),
                    startDate.getMonth() + 1,
                    startDate.getDate(),
                    startDate.getHours(),
                    startDate.getMinutes(),
                ],
                end: [
                    endDate.getFullYear(),
                    endDate.getMonth() + 1,
                    endDate.getDate(),
                    endDate.getHours(),
                    endDate.getMinutes(),
                ],
                organizer: {
                    name: "Test Test",
                    email: "souf@test.test", //for testing
                    },
                method: "REQUEST",
                title: `${deal.title} (${deal.reference})`,
                description: deal.summary,
                location: addressToString(customer.address),
                status: "CONFIRMED",
                attendees: [{
                    name: "Test",
                    email: "kri@test.test",
                    rsvp: true,
                    role: 'REQ-PARTICIPANT',
                    partstat: 'NEEDS-ACTION',
                }],
            };
```

and the output afterwards read out of notepad is:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
PRODID:adamgibbons/ics
METHOD:REQUEST
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT1H
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:dadb3c31-25e9-4026-9878-c1001f4e9a39
SUMMARY:Offerte V1 LG / 1 buiten unit & 1 binnen unit (P4660)
DTSTAMP:20201012T135254Z
DTSTART:20201015T070000Z
DTEND:20201015T150000Z
LOCATION:
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN=Test Test:mailto:souf@test.test
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;CN=Test:mailt
    o:kri@test.test
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

The message must have the VCALENDAR above as the one and only MIME part, not an attachment. The message content type must be "text/calendar"